# Will publishing a first author paper in ICECE2020 conference help me when applying for a PhD admission in the USA?

Tags: publications, phd, graduate-admissions, conference, paper-submission

I am in undergraduate. I wish to apply for scholarship to do PHD in the USA. Will publishing a paper in this conference (http://icece.buet.ac.bd/2020/) help me get funding?

It does not seem like a very reputable conference. However, I am not sure if my paper will be accepted in top tier conferences. So, is this conference 'better than nothing'? How much can a paper here help me?
thank you.

Comment: I don't know why you consider it not very reputable. I hope not just because it is held in Bangladesh. The university sponsoring it is over 100 years old.

Comment: @Buffy
actually i do consider it not reputable because it is held in a third world country. The university does produce many undergraduates who go on to top universities all over the world. Unfortunately, due to low budget the university faculty cannot do a lot of research. 
I am still in undergrad, so don't know much about post grad stuff. But, I have heard from a few seniors that such conferences from our country don't mean much to the grad admissions committee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you take every opportunity open to you to do research and publish it. It will never hurt unless you publish in predatory venues.

The university sponsoring this conference is reputable (and has a long history). The conference is in their main line of interest. I don't think you should have any qualms about submitting to such a conference.

While it might be a bit "better" to publish via a conference in EU, say, or US, it is probably financially impossible. Take advantage of all opportunities as you start on what you hope is a long career. Small first steps can be positive steps.

People elsewhere will understand these things in evaluating your work.

Comment: Thank you. (I seem to not have enough points to up vote)

As a student from this country,  financial burden of publishing in foreign conferences really is troublesome.